# How to create dataframe of tokenized words (columns) per sentence (rows)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following text:

**"Hi there, my name is sam! I love spicy hand pulled noodles. I also like to game alot."**

My goal is to convert this paragraph into a dataframe of tokenized words per sentences. (Where the number of rows is equal to the number of sentences, and the number of columns is equal to the number of words in the longest sentence).

I start off creating a dataframe of tokenized sentences:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

df = pd.DataFrame({"sentences": sent_tokenize(paragraph)})
```

The result is:

```
    sentences
0   Hi there, my name is sam!
1   I love spicy hand pulled noodles.
2   I also like to game alot.
```

Then I converted each sentence (row) into a list of tokenized words:

```
df["tokens"] = df.sentences.apply(word_tokenize)
```

The result is (if i print that column alone):

```
0    [Hi, there, ,, my, name, is, sam, !]
1    [I, love, spicy, hand, pulled, noodles, .]
2    [I, also, like, to, game, alot, .]
```

What I'd like to happen next is something like this **(need help here)**:

```
      w1   w2     w3      w4     w5       w6       w7     w8
0     Hi   there  ,       my     name     is       sam    !
1     I    love   spicy   hand   pulled   noodles  .      NaN
2     I    also   like    to     game     alot     .      NaN
```

Where the number of columns is equal to the length of the longest word_tokenized sentence. For the sentences shorter than the longest one, I'd like the empty columns to contain NaN values (or even 0.0). Is there a way to achieve this with pandas commands?

Comment: is fine to count from 0? like w0, w1 and so on

Comment: yeah that's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 1st prefixed column starts with `1` (`w1`):

```
In [350]: df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['tokens'].tolist(), columns=[f'w{i}' for i in range(1, df['tokens'].str.len().max() + 1)])).fillna(np.nan)               
Out[350]: 
                           sentences                                      tokens  w1     w2     w3    w4      w5       w6   w7   w8
0          Hi there, my name is sam!        [Hi, there, ,, my, name, is, sam, !]  Hi  there      ,    my    name       is  sam    !
1  I love spicy hand pulled noodles.  [I, love, spicy, hand, pulled, noodles, .]   I   love  spicy  hand  pulled  noodles    .  NaN
2          I also like to game alot.          [I, also, like, to, game, alot, .]   I   also   like    to    game     alot    .  NaN
```

---

If you need it as a separate dataframe:

```
In [352]: pd.DataFrame(df['tokens'].tolist(), columns=[f'w{i}' for i in range(1, df['tokens'].str.len().max() + 1)]).fillna(np.nan)                        
Out[352]: 
   w1     w2     w3    w4      w5       w6   w7   w8
0  Hi  there      ,    my    name       is  sam    !
1   I   love  spicy  hand  pulled  noodles    .  NaN
2   I   also   like    to    game     alot    .  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
pd.DataFrame(data = df.tokens.tolist()).fillna(pd.np.nan).add_prefix('w')
```

output:

[image]